# Clickable Cell in Kendo Grid

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a grid,with one column,every time i look for something using a text box i have,this one column grid shows a list of items which i should be able to click on each item ,means make them clickable,i know i can put button there but i want the i item clickable,any suggestion?

$("#TurbineType").click(function () {
            var drp = document.getElementById('autocomplete').value;

```
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("turbineTypeList","AdminTool")",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({ "turbineName": drp, }),

            success: function (result) {
                $("#turbingrid_Device").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: result,
                    //editable: "inline",
                    //editable: true,
                    //height: 'auto',
                    scrollable: true,

                    //toolbar: ["save", "cancel"],
                    //sortable: { mode: "single", allowUnsort: true },
                    columns: [
                                          { field: 'Text', title: 'DeviceType', width: '100px' },
                                           { command: { text: "View Details"}, title: " ", width: "50px" }
                    ]

                });

            }
        })
            });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
$("#grid").on("click", "td", function(e) {    
});
```

in order to subscribe to a click event on grid cells once the grid has been initialized.

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/PgeYC/42/)

### EDIT

After clearing up the question in the comment below, you can display column values as hyperlinks by using the column `template` and `href`, like follows:

```
columns: [{ field: "URL", title: "URL", template: '<a href="\\#">#=Title#</a>'}]
```

Here is another [Dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/aFAR/528) to demonstrate.

Comment: Sorry i got mistake,i meant,make it kind of (link)when you mouse over ,items are like link,for this i should use "link" ..or?

Comment: See the updates applied to the question above, which will allow you to display data in the style of a hyperlink in your kendo grid columns.

Comment: NP, happy to help - don't forget to hit the vote up button for questions which solve problems for you!! ;)